# OpenSUSE Tumbleweed after update graphic mode fails

Tags: drivers, opensuse

I used the package updater to install the latest patches und updates this morning. Since init 5 i.e. graphic mode doesen't work anymore!

```
NAME="openSUSE Tumbleweed"
VERSION="20230301"
ID="opensuse-tumbleweed"
ID_LIKE="opensuse suse"
VERSION_ID="20230301"
PRETTY_NAME="openSUSE Tumbleweed"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:opensuse:tumbleweed:20230301"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.opensuse.org"
HOME_URL="https://www.opensuse.org/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Tumbleweed"
LOGO="distributor-logo-Tumbleweed"
uname -r shows me: 6.2.0-1-default
```

in the warn-log I found:

```
2023-03-03T09:21:35.968091+01:00 spica /usr/libexec/gdm/gdm-x-session[2132]: (EE) AIGLX error: dlopen of /usr/lib64/dri/i965_dri.so failed (/usr/lib64/dri/i965_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
2023-03-03T09:21:35.968127+01:00 spica /usr/libexec/gdm/gdm-x-session[2132]: (EE) AIGLX error: unable to load driver i965
```

Note: I changed from Leap 15.4 to tumbleweed just because Leap did not recognize the core i5 integrated graphic driver i965. Intel-drivers are directly supported by OpenSUSE normally! But the latest patch must be buggy!

How can I rollback?

Comment: It's saying the file cannot be found, not that there is a problem with it. You can use yast to find the package which contains it, and it should return `Mesa-dri`. Ensure that his is installed.

Comment: Remember graphic mode doesn't work anymore after the update! I used the package actualizer, hence I was in graphic mode on starting the update. I have used before Yast in Text mode, but this is not transparent at all. But meanwhile  I did a zypper dup in text mode. Maybe this fixed the problem, maybe not! Until now I was only remote with ssh on the machine, hence I don't know.

Comment: You don't `need` graphics mode. Your reply is also confusing, since you are suggesting it now works.